# Provide a download link to the user from a direct link without saving file in server

Tags: node.js

I want to create an Express App to provide download links for user.
I put a direct link to a route, and the user is directed to download directly
Like this :
https://myserver.com/?url=(some direct link to file)&type=(file extension)&dlheader=(file type)/(file extension)&title=(file name to download)
Note: the direct link is from other server

Answer (score 0):

You can take url query paramaters and send files via node.js like this. But you didn't provide information about where is your files on server.

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {

    // take paramaters from url
    const url = req.query.url;
    const type= req.query.type;
    const dlheader= req.query.dlheader;
    const title= req.query.title;

    //then send file
    res.sendFile(`/your/file/path/${title}.${type}`)
});
```

Comment: the direct link is from other server

Comment: @YacineDjenidi so just res.redirect(url) will solve the issue